# Ajax-render a table which is inside a different form

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I am facing a problem rendering a `data table` when selecting a date from `<rich:calendar>`. I use `<a4j:ajax>` for the rendering but with no effect. Here is the code sample:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <rich:panel header="#{lang.reportPanelHeader}" id="panel" rendered="#{navigation.reportRendered}" width="700px" style="margin-left:250px">
        <a4j:status onstart="#{rich:component('statPane')}.show()" onstop="#{rich:component('statPane')}.hide()" />
        <h:form id="data_table_form">
            <rich:dataTable value="#{validateReportAction.reportList}" var="report" iterationStatusVar="it" id="data_table" rows="5">
               <rich:column>
                   <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                   #{it.index  + 1}
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column>
                   ....
               </rich:column>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <rich:dataScroller page="#{validateReportAction.page}" />
                </f:facet>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </h:form>

        <rich:popupPanel id="statPane" autosized="true" style="border: none; background-color: #e6e6e6;">
            ....
        </rich:popupPanel>

        <div id="bottom">
            <h:form id="calendarForm">
                <div id="left">                
                    <div class="input" id="test_cal">
                        <rich:calendar 
                            dataModel="#{calendarModel}"
                            value="#{validateReportAction.selectedDate}"
                            boundaryDatesMode="scroll"
                            required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="#{lang.dateRequiredMsg}" 
                            mode="ajax"
                            id="date"
                            datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
                            popup="false">

                            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="@all"/>

                        </rich:calendar>

                        <span class="error_msg">
                            <rich:message for="date" ajaxRendered="true"/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </rich:panel>

</ui:composition>
```

I am forced to use @all in the calendar in `<a4j:ajax event="change" render="@all"/>`  but I want to render only the `data table`. How can I do this?

Comment: You have by the way syntax errors in your markup. The opening and closing tags do not match. But that would already have thrown a Facelets exception upon viewing the page. Please be careful with preparing snippets in the question :)

Comment: :> I will take that in mind thanks :-))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's located in a different naming container parent, you need to refer it by its absolute client ID. To find it out, open the page in the webbrowser. Rightclick and *View Source*. Locate the HTML `<table>` element which is generated by `<rich:dataTable id="data_table">`. It'll look something like this:

```
<table id="data_table_form:data_table">
```

You need to take exactly that ID, prefix with the JSF naming container separator character (which defaults to `:`) and use it in the `render` attribute.

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" render=":data_table_form:data_table" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

Comment: It is not working for me even after adding prefix as : to the full Id

Comment: @Harshal_Kalavadiya: Then you don't have the same problem as the OP. Head to https://stackoverflow.com/q/8634156 for a bit more general explanation on the matter.